# Create Bookmarks programmatically in IBM Connections Communities

Tags: api, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am trying to add Bookmarks programmatically to a Community in IBM Connections.

Following the IBM documentation (http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+5.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Retrieving_a_remote_applications_list_ic50&content=apicontent)

I am sending a request to   /communities/service/atom/community/bookmarks?communityUuid=''
in the response I am looking for of  element that has a rel="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/bookmarks" 
Which doesn't exist in my case.

I try to post the Bookmarks document to couple of link:
/communities/service/atom/community/bookmarks/service?communityUuid=

and

/communities/service/atom/community/bookmarks?communityUuid=

None of them works.

Any idea of the correct URL to add Bookmarks programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Flavien you should reference http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Working_with_community_bookmarks_programmatically_ic50&content=apicontent

Community Bookmarks is a slightly different implementation than the Bookmarks standalone application.

POST to /communities/service/atom/community/bookmarks?communityUuid=

Example. https://greenhouse.lotus.com/communities/service/atom/community/bookmarks?communityUuid=3a246a15-b4d6-44e1-a01d-1c3d89f1f9a4

You'll get a 201 if the resource is recorded.

Comment: Thanks, my issue was in the Atom entry I was sending. I was using the same one than for a standalone Bookmark.